# can't compile .cpp file with clang even after installing clang3.8

Tags: apt, 15.10, sudo, c++, clang

I installed clang3.8 with bunch of other packages that I usually need, after a fresh installation of Ubuntu 15.10 using following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install clang-3.8 clang-3.8-doc libclang-common-3.8-dev libclang-3.8-dev libclang1-3.8 libclang1-3.8-dbg libllvm-3.8-ocaml-dev libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8-dbg lldb-3.8 llvm-3.8 llvm-3.8-dev llvm-3.8-doc llvm-3.8-examples llvm-3.8-runtime clang-format-3.8 python-clang-3.8 lldb-3.8-dev liblldb-3.8-dbg mongodb-org oracle-java8-installer codeblocks
```

but when I execute 'clang' command from terminal to check if its installed correctly the I get following result:

```
$ clang
The program 'clang' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install clang
```

and

```
$ clang++
The program 'clang' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install clang
```

What do I do?

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

installs version 3.6 which is not latest stable release; and I have already installed latest stable release which is 3.8.

Comment: You can see the files installed by each package with `for i in  clang-3.8 clang-3.8-doc libclang-common-3.8-dev libclang-3.8-dev libclang1-3.8 libclang1-3.8-dbg libllvm-3.8-ocaml-dev libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8-dbg lldb-3.8 llvm-3.8 llvm-3.8-dev llvm-3.8-doc llvm-3.8-examples llvm-3.8-runtime clang-format-3.8 python-clang-3.8 lldb-3.8-dev liblldb-3.8-dbg mongodb-org oracle-java8-installer codeblocks
; do  ; echo "$i"; dpkg -L $i;done`. If you pipe the result to `|grep /bin/` you will see the executables.

Answer (score 0):

I checked /usr/bin/ and I saw clang++-3.8 and clang-3.8. I guess I have to make aliases for them in bashrc, but why didn't they get install with normal names like clang or clang++?